# How do can I duplicate a MySql database with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a chat app in Java and I've hit a road bump. I want there to be multiple chat rooms, and those chat rooms can contain multiple people. I feel like to do this by code, every time a user creates a chatroom, it should create a new database and use that. What I want to do is just have a template database, and then duplicate it with different names. I know there might be security issues like setting the users allowed to access it, but I have no idea on what else I could do. For further explanation, the server I'm using is not local host, it is in a remote location so I can't just simply send a command with terminal.

This is the code I used to do what I wanted, but with a table instead of an entire database. Hopefully it might give you some more info on what I want/need.

```
int updateTable = st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE chat_room_" + df.format(num) + " LIKE chat_room_temp");
```

Comment: No you don’t need a different table or database for every chat room. You are overcomplicating this.

Comment: @NathanHughes how will you suggest I do this?

Comment: Make a table for chat rooms. When a user creates a chat room put a row in the table. Use intersection tables with FK constraints to specify which users see which chat rooms. You don’t gain anything but complication adding more databases.

Comment: @NathanHughes where would the messages be stored

Comment: @NathanHughes what if i just have a table called messages
it will say what chatroom its for and who sent it aswell as the message
then i have a sperate table called chatrooms whitch will have a list of people who are in it
is that good?

Comment: That way is not as normalized. Try to normalize as much as you can, it minimizes the amount of special logic you have to write code for.

Comment: The fact your server is remote does not necessarily mean you cannot have terminal access (e.g. through SSH).